# jQuery slideToggle runs complete function but doesn't toggle on mobile

Tags: jquery

I'm using slideToggle with a complete function to toggle a class.

```
        $('article h2:first-of-type').click(function(){

        var $_this = $(this);

        $(this).next('.show').slideToggle('fast', function(){
            $_this.toggleClass('closed open');
        });
    });
```

This works as expected on desktop, and even on mobile, some of the time.  The problem is that on mobile, specifically iPhone 4s and 5(but not in iOS simulator), the first time the h2 is touched, it runs the complete function and toggles the class but doesn't slide down.  A subsequent touch will slide down, but at that point the classes are inverse to what they should be.  Im not sure why this is happening.

Comment: html5 may be not supported....

Comment: Aren't you using jQuery mobile?

Comment: No. Im not using jQuery mobile.  Its a responsive site in which sections that are open on desktop collapse into an accordion style view on mobile.